Can we find conditions on $x,y,z,d$ such that $gcd(a,b,c)>1$
Let us consider an equation of the form
$$ax+by+cz=d$$
where $a,x,b,y,c,z,d$ are integers with $a>1,b>1,c>1$. From this equation, $gcd(a,b,c)$ divide $d$.
My question is: Can we find conditions on $x,y,z,d$ such that $gcd(a,b,c)>1$ and $a,b,c$ verifying an equation of the form $g(a,b,c)=0$.

what is that function $g(a,b,c)$ of your last edit?

If $a,b,c>1$ then their sum is $\ge 6$.

If $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ then, by Bezout's, $x$, $y$, $z$ and $d$ can be whatever integers. Thus, no condition about $x,y,z,d$ can grant that $\gcd(a,b,c)>1$.

I means, is there existe a way to force the $gcd$ to be greater than 1.

It seems there isn't.

$a,b,c$ verifying an equation of the form $g(a,b,c)=0$.

Consider the solution set $x, y, z$ of
$$a^*x+b^*y+c^*z=d^*$$
where $gcd(a^*,b^*,c^*)=1$.
Then clearly for any $k\in\mathbb Z\backslash \{0\}$ and $a=ka^*, b=kb^*, c=kc^*, d=kd^*$ the very same set solves your
$$ax+by+cz=d$$
as well and then $gcd(a,b,c) = k$ clearly.
However whenever say $gcd(a^*,k)=n>1$, then furthermore
$$(a/n)(nx)+by+cz=d$$
here would be met as well, where you still have $gcd((a/n),b,c)=k$.
